# Удаление событий Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Кликаю по элементу, открывается инпут - ввожу новое значение, затем кликаю вне его (происходит сохранение значения), но при этом попадаю на тот же класс который сразу приводит к ОТКРЫТИЮ инпута на рядом стоящем элементе , а надо бы это предотвратить По сути сделать редактирование по клику на элемент и сохранение по клику вне его. То что попадаю на тот же самый класс который строкой ниже - этого не избежать

```
`  $(document).on('click', '.hours_waiting', function (event) {
        var elem = $(this);

        var elem_class = elem.attr('class').split(' ').shift();
        var old_val = elem.text().trim();
        var el_w = elem.width() + 10;
        //инпута для ввобода нового значения
        elem.html('<input value="' + old_val + '" type="text"  name="' + elem_class + '" style="width:' + el_w + 'px; height: auto;" class="now_edited">');
        var el_in = elem.find('input');
        var name = el_in.attr('name');
        var task_id = elem.parent('tr').data('id');

        el_in
            .focus()
            .off('blur')
            .on('blur', function (event) {

            //здесь идут действия после срабатывания клика вне элемента el_in(но клик попадает снова на класс hours_waiting но другого td
            //соответственно срабатывает сразу событие  $(document).on('click', '.hours_waiting'), что надо предотвратить, off('click') не помогает`
```

Comment: А почему это надо предотвратить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удаления обработчика события используется `off` описание работы: http://api.jquery.com/off/

```js
function flash() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .on( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Can Click!" );
});
$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .off( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Does nothing..." );
});
```

```css
  button {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  button#theone {
    color: red;
    back
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>off demo</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="theone">Does nothing...</button>
<button id="bind">Add Click</button>
<button id="unbind">Remove Click</button>
<div style="display:none;">Click!</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в моем случае, куда off поставить?

Comment: elem.off('click') в событии blur не работает, походу надо переписать все

Comment: @игорь88 off принимает как минимум два параметра: 1. имя события. 2. функция-обработчик, которая была передана в on. Чтобы все работало корректно, нужно вынести в отдельную функцию то, что передается вторым параметром в .on('blur',